ctypes.c_char versus ctypes.c_ubyte
I can define a structure containing an array of bytes in two ways, as an array of c_char or an array of c_ubyte:
import ctypes
                                 
class Char(ctypes.Structure):                 
    _fields_ = [('value',ctypes.c_char * 12)] 
                                              
class Byte(ctypes.Structure):                 
    _fields_ = [('value',ctypes.c_ubyte * 12)]

I can assign a value to an instance of Char() very straightforwardly:
>>> ci = Char()        
>>> ci.value = b'Hello world'
>>> print(ci.value)
b'Hello world'     

But if I try the analagous assignment to a Byte() instance I get a TypeError:
>>> bi = Byte()                                         
>>> bi.value = b'Hello world'                           
Traceback (most recent call last):                      
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                   
TypeError: expected c_ubyte_Array_12 instance, got bytes

C doesn't really have a byte type so I am OK about using c_char, but I feel that using ctypes c_ubyte reveals my intention more clearly, which is why I tried it.
Is there a good reason why one should not be allowed to assign Python bytes to a ctypes.c_ubyte array? It seems odd to me, so I worry there is something I am not understanding about c_ubyte.

c_char has special default handling in structures that treat it as a null-terminated string.  c_ubyte (and c_byte, the signed version) don't do that.  You can still assign to them with byte string, but need to use slicing and assign a byte string the same size as the slice:
import ctypes

class Char(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('value',ctypes.c_char * 12)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Char({self.value})'

class Byte(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('value', ctypes.c_ubyte * 12)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Byte({bytes(self.value)})'

c = Char()
print(c.value)  # converted to byte string. doesn't show nulls
c.value = b'hello'
print(c)  # b'hello'
c.value = b'123456789abc'
print(c)  # b'123456789abc'
try:
    c.value = b'123456789abcd'  # error: too long
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

b = Byte()
print(b.value)  # still an array
b.value[:5] = b'hello'  # assign 5-byte string to 5-byte slice.
print(b)  # shows nulls
b.value[6:8] = b'XX'
print(b)  # any slice, even after nulls
b.value[:] = b'123456789abc'  # array size is 12, string exactly fits, no nulls
print(b)
try:
    b.value[:] = b'123456789ab'  # array size is 12, byte string is 11, error: too short
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

Output:
b''
Char(b'hello')
Char(b'123456789abc')
bytes too long (13, maximum length 12)
<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_12 object at 0x0000022D5EC2DAD0>
Byte(b'hello\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
Byte(b'hello\x00XX\x00\x00\x00\x00')
Byte(b'123456789abc')
Can only assign sequence of same size

